# Change file extension?

Tags: java, file-rename

What the best way is change file extension of Java?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please give an example.

Comment: user goes to website, I change user file extention from exe to txt example

Comment: still not clear. what file, what user, what website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should get familiar with [What file extension is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_extension).

Next correct Your question, do You want only change it or how to change it.

If You only want to change it, the we can assume that the extension i really there.

But for answer how to change extension. The answer should provide information about finding one, parsing properly the string etc...

And you should also define what the best mean for You.

For me best solution would be.

1 - Retrieve the characters after after last index of '.'.

2 - Verify that string if any in defined extensions by system.

3 - If found remove it,

4 - Add to file name new extension.

Answer (score 4):

Just rename it using [File.renameTo(String name)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

```
 public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

// Construct the file object from existing file.
File f = new File("myfile.toto"); 

// Rename it
f.renameTo(new File("myfile.myext"));
```

}

Comment: My answer works for Java where your question was originally postedand not Javascript

Comment: <script type="text/java">public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

// Construct the file object from existing file.
File f = new File("myfile.toto"); 

// Rename it
f.renameTo(new File("myfile.myext"));
}</script> do not work !!

Comment: my example is a full Java application with a main method. Just use: File f = new File("myfile.toto"); 
f.renameTo(new File("myfile.myext"));

Comment: did not know to use it. bad implementation

Comment: `<script type="text/java">` what do you think that does, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell:

```
cat abc.data | %{$_ -replace " ",","} | sc abc.csv
```

Using Unix Sed command:

```
sed 's/ /,/g' abc.data > abc.csv
```